# Is there a more python way of quarterising a column from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column within a pandas dataframe with the range 1-843300 which I want to split into 4 equal parts for pd.cut purposes. I was wondering what the most pythonic way of doing this is?

The df is called 'news_df' column label is 'shares' and here's how I've done it:

```
max_shares = news_df.shares.max()
weight_bins = [1,max_shares*0.25,max_shares*0.5,max_shares*0.75,max_shares]
```

I'm using Python 3.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can do this one step with pd.qcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpys linspace to do that.

```
import numpy as np
max_shares = 10 
weight_bins = np.linspace(0, max_shares, 5)
weight_bins[0] = 1
array([  1. ,   2.5,   5. ,   7.5,  10. ])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html#pandas-qcut)

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Range':np.arange(1,14)})


    Range
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
10     11
11     12

df.assign(qbins = pd.qcut(df.Range, 4, labels=['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th']))
```

Output:

```
    Range qbins
0       1   1st
1       2   1st
2       3   1st
3       4   2nd
4       5   2nd
5       6   2nd
6       7   3rd
7       8   3rd
8       9   3rd
9      10   4th
10     11   4th
11     12   4th
```